# jQuery Change Value of Clicked button with $(this) selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to update the text of a button when it is clicked. I have a number of buttons with the same class but no id. Why doesn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qU5tR/7/) work?

```
<input type="button" class="add-button" value="Default" />
<input type="button" class="add-button" value="Default" />
<input type="button" class="add-button" value="Default" />
<input type="button" class="add-button" value="Default" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-button').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
        $(this).html('Changed');
    });
});​
```

The alert is triggered, but the button isn't changed.

Comment: for more dynamic, you can use `on('click', handler)`, it will bind the event for new buttons created on run time

Comment: @Vdt No, in the form you have written it, it won't.

Comment: @bažmegakapa yeah ... it should be `$(wrapper).on('click', '.add-button', handler())` , wrapper can be any element that wrap those buttons. body is a good example.

Comment: Is this question is answered, please feel free to accept,upvote the best suited answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `this.value` for `input`. See below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-button').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
        this.value = 'Changed';
    });
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qU5tR/10/

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get this working after adding `$(this).button('refresh')` after the `this.value = 'Changed'` because I am using jQuery mobile which I neglected to mention.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 $(this).val("changed");
```

`html()` only replace `innerHtml`. it does not change button value.

Answer (score 2):

You want to change it's value, not html. It doesn't have html children.

```
$(this).val('Changed');
```

or

```
this.value = "Changed";
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is

```
$(this).val('Changed');
```

instead of

```
$(this).html('Changed');
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are input buttons which have no innerHTML, to set the button text you have to set the button's value attribute or value property.

```
$(this).attr('value', 'Changed'); /* Change value attribute */
// or this.value = 'Changed';     /* Change value property */
```

Comment: Please note that the two examples are not equivalent. One is changing the attribute, the other is changing the property.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ways to do it correctly:

You are trying to change the value, so use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
 $(this).val('Changed');
```

You can also simply use `this.value = 'Changed';`, because `value` is a cross-browser DOM property, or even the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
$(this).prop('value', 'Changed');
```

#### Why it did not work:

`.html()` changes the content of the element and the `input` element can have no content, it has no closing tag. It would work with a `<button>` element though, it has a closing tag and content.

Answer (score 1):

Change value instead of html. jQuery content of form filed can be changed by val.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-button').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
        $(this).val('Changed'); // or this.value == 'Changed';
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
this.value = 'changed' ;
```

This is faster than `$(this).val('changed');`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3z3Th/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `.attr()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-button').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
        $(this).attr( 'value', 'NEW_TEXT');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you button doesn't contain any html. So you can change it or set it. What you need is:

```
$(this).val("Changed");
```